# is there any easy way to convert int type to enum type in c language?

Tags: c, casting, enums, int

How to cast int to enum in c?

```
enum a b;
int c;

b = (a)c;
```

it doesn't work.
error message is that 'a' undeclared

(in gcc)

Answer (score 3):

As you seem to already know from declaring the variable, enum types must be prefixed with the word `enum`.

```
b = (enum a)c;
```

Comment: And `enum` types are integer types, so C does not require the cast when assigning an `enum` value to an `int`.